# Asynchronously execute method with callback in Python 2.6

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I am trying to execute a time-consuming back-end job, executed by a front-end call. This back-end job should execute a callback method when it is completed, which will release a semaphore. The front end shouldn't have to wait for the long process to finish in order to get a response from the call to kick off the job.

I'm trying to use the Pool class from the multiprocessing library to solve this issue, but I'm running into some issues. Namely that it seems like the only way to actually execute the method passed into apply_async is to call the .get() method in the ApplyResult object that is returned by the apply_async call.

In order to solve this, I thought to create a Process object with the target being apply_result.get. But this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a basic understanding that I'm missing here? What would you folks suggest to solve this issue.

Here is a snippet example of what I have right now:

```
p = Pool(1)
result = p.apply_async(long_process, args=(config, requester), callback=complete_long_process)
Process(target=result.get).start()
response = {'status': 'success', 'message': 'Job started for {0}'.format(requester)}
return jsonify(response)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you would need a Process object here. Look at this snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from itertools import repeat
from time import sleep

def complete_long_process(foo):
    print "completed", foo

def long_process(a,b):
    print a,b
    sleep(10)    

p = Pool(1)
result = p.apply_async(long_process, args=(1, 42),
                       callback=complete_long_process)

print "submitted"
sleep(20)
```

If I understand what  you are trying to achieve, this does exactly that. As soon as you call apply_async, it launches long_process function and execution of the main program continues. As soon as it completes, complete_long_process is called. There is no need to use get method to execute long_process, and the code does not block and wait anything.

If your long_process does not appear to run, I assume your problem is somewhere within long_process.

Hannu